# Why is the det(A) computed as it is?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm looking [at how to compute the determinant of a matrix *A*](https://mathinsight.org/determinant_matrix), and it is mentioned that for a $2\times2$ matrix with elements `[a b][c d]` , it is given by `ad - bc`. Now about the $3\times3$ case, I understood how you compute it. But **why** are the signs `- +`? And why does this become `- + -` for a $4\times4$ case, and `- + - +` for the $5\times5$ case, and etc? Specifically, I'm wondering what is the basis for the signs in computing the `det(A)`.

Comment: This is a deep question, actually.

Comment: I was told it is related to the [parity of a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation), but that's all I know.

Comment: Isn't it "+-" ? There is a so-called chess-board-rule which we need for the laplace expansion. The upper-left sign is always "+"

Comment: You have to go deep into the details: $\det$ is an alternating $n$-linear map such that $\det(I_n)=1$, and it can be shown based on those two properties that, $$\det A=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\sigma}A_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots A_{n,\sigma(n)}$$ from which the computational formula that you described can be derived. The plus and minus signs come from the $(-1)^{\sigma}$ part.

Comment: Are you looking only how to *compute* determinants, or did you have a look to a precise *definition* of what the determinant is ?

Comment: @StupidQuestionsInc: $(-1)^{\sigma}$ is meaningless if $\sigma\in S_n$.

Comment: @Bernard it's just a different way to write $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Hard to answer. I was looking at how you compute them, and the example that I linked was easy enough to follow if I believe the algorithm that they provide in the page. But this left me wondering about the sign. I'm sure this is some fundamental derivation that I've missed somewhere...

Comment: @StupidQuestionsInc: Usually this is simply denoted $\varepsilon(\sigma)$.

Comment: @Sos Well, I mean that if you want to understand why we compute determinants like that, you have to look to what a determinant is. A determinant is not just a "number" associated to a matrix, it is a very fundamental object that has a very precise definition, and multiple interpretations. If you want to understand why it is computed with such a method, you have to look to these kind of things (and I encourage you to do this !). Otherwise, if you just want to compute determinants, just learn the method and forget the deep reason "why" :)

Answer (score 2):

The rules the OP posted are practical rules in the sense that these are the rules to explicitly calculate the determinant of $A$. To understand the signs, however, it might be convenient to use the *definition* of determinant of a square matrix $A=(a_{ij})$. Here $A$ is assumed to be a $n\times n$ matrix. This is more elaborate formula, and it reads:

\begin{eqnarray}
\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}\epsilon_{\sigma}\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i,\sigma(i)}\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
You can find a more extensive discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) but let me explain what are these factors and why it explains the signs on the OP question. Because you are dealing with $n\times n$ matrices, consider the set $I_{n}:=\{1,...,n\}$. A permutation of this set is simply a bijective function $\sigma: I_{n}\to I_{n}$. The set of all such permutations is denoted by $S_{n}$ (if you know what a group is, $S_{n}$ is a group with composition as its product). Thus, the first sum on (\ref{1}) is a sum over all permutations of $I_{n}$ or, alternatively, a sum over all permutations $\sigma \in S_{n}$.

Now, take $a\neq b$ with $a,b \in I_{n}$ and let $\tau$ be a permutation defined as follows: $\tau(a) = b$, $\tau(b) =a$ and $\tau(k) = k$ if $k \not\in \{a,b\}$. Intuitively, this is a permutation that only exchanges $a$ and $b$. Such a permutation (i.e. a permutation that exchanges only two different elements of $I_{n}$) is called a *transposition*. It is a known result that every permutation $\sigma$ has a decomposition in transpositions, that is, given $\sigma \in S_{n}$ we can also write $\sigma$ as a product (actually composites of) transpositions $\sigma = \tau_{1}\cdots\tau_{k}$. Is this decomposition unique? The answer is **no**; however, the parity of $k$ is. What this means is that if a permutation $\sigma$ can be written as a product of an *even* (respectivelly *odd*) number of transpositions, then *every* decomposition of $\sigma$ into a product of transpositions contains an even (respectivelly odd) number of transpositions. Thus, we can characterize *every* permutation by its parity: permutations with $k$ even are called even and are associated to a number $1$; permutations with $k$ odd are called odd and are associated with a number $-1$. Generically, we write $\epsilon_{\sigma}$ to represent either $1$ or $-1$, according to the $\sigma$. Because $\epsilon_{\sigma}= \pm $, we call this number the *sign* of the permutation $\sigma$.

Now, to finally answer your question, note that together with $\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}$, (\ref{1}) has a weight $\epsilon_{\sigma}$ which can take values $\epsilon_{\sigma} = \pm$, according to what permutation $\sigma$ is being considered. This is the reason why the determinant formula has a bunch of plus and minus signs; this comes from its definition. However, because (\ref{1}) is usually very difficult to handle, it is more convenient to evaluate determinants using other (more practical, convenient) rules.

*Note:* I'm sorry if the answer was too long and too detailed, but this is the best way to understand these ideas in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

An $(n\times n)$-matrix $[A]$ numerically describes an affine transformation $A:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n$. Such a transformation maps any  set $S\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ to some image set $A(S)\subset{\mathbb R}^n$. It is a basic geometric fact  that the volumes of  all sets $S\subset {\mathbb R}^n$ are multiplied by the same factor $\lambda\geq 0$:
$${\rm vol}\bigl(A(S)\bigr)=\lambda \>{\rm vol(S)}\ .$$
This factor $\lambda$ depends on the map $A$, hence on the given matrix $[A]$.

It follows that there is a function $\lambda:\>A\mapsto \lambda(A)$ that assigns to each $(n\times n)$-matrix $[A]$ its "volume scaling factor". Thinking a long time about this problem one finds that  there is a function $${\rm det}:\quad{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}\to{\mathbb R},\qquad [A]\mapsto {\rm det}\bigl[A]$$
that does the trick. This function is polynomial in the variables $a_{ik}$ forming the elements of the matrix $[A]$, with lots of symmetries, and sign rules. One then has
$$\lambda(A)=\bigl|\,{\rm det}[A]\,\bigr|\ .$$
There is no one line explanation of this result. One has to go through the proof given in any linear algebra textbook.